# GraphQL execution slow and incorrect

Tags: graphql, apollo

I have built my first GraphQL server in NodeJS to query a MySQL database using Sequelize and Apollo.

SQL commands run fast (as normal) but GraphQL queries are timing out, and returning incomplete data. So there are two issues I am facing:

- Why is my GraphQL API querying so slowly?
- How do I ensure I get all thedata that I need?

I have [created a Stackblitz for this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-beravi?file=database.js,server.js,schema%2Funits_topics_activities.js,schema%2Fa_working.js,models%2Finit-models.js,schema%2Funits_topics.js), and built a new test MySQL database. Unfortunately the stackblitz doesnt seem to be able to connect to a DB (either my real one or the test one, both work on my local version with the same code) but the structure is visible.

The GraphQL query I am trying to run is this:

```
query UnitTopicActivity($unitTopicActivityId: ID!) {
  unitTopicActivity(id: $unitTopicActivityId) {
    activity_id
    activity_specific_id
    id
    topic_id
    topic {
      name
      description
      id
      image
    }
    activity {
      ... on Working {
        name
      }
      ... on Experiment {
        name
      }
      ... on PhetLab {
        name
      }
      ... on VideoNote {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With variables

```
{
  "unitTopicActivityId": 192
}
```

The output I **expect** is:

```
{
  "data": {
    "unitTopicActivity": {
      "activity_id": 5,
      "activity_specific_id": 44,
      "id": "193",
      "topic_id": 73,
      "topic": {
        "name": "Complex Energy Problems",
        "description": "This is topic you will be required to use all you know of energy and work to solve some complex problems.",
        "id": "73",
        "image": ""
      },
      "activity": [ // not sure about what this should look like to be honest as I havent been able to generate it yet but this best guess.
          { 
              "working": { 
                  "name": "Working Activity"
               }
          },
          { 
              "experiment": { 
                  "name": "Experiment Activity"
               }
          }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What I **get** is (This single query takes 5.6 seconds):

```
{
  "data": {
    "unitTopicActivity": {
      "activity_id": 5,
      "activity_specific_id": 44,
      "id": "193",
      "topic_id": 73,
      "topic": {
        "name": "Complex Energy Problems",
        "description": "This is topic you will be required to use all you know of energy and work to solve some complex problems.",
        "id": "73",
        "image": ""
      },
      "activity": null
    }
  }
}
```

If I try to run the query that does this for everyone of the items then I get some data but then a timeout in the code as it hits the execution limit in my database.js.

**Edit - Some other info about similar querys:**

This is a simple query and runs fast enough (631ms non local db for 165 rows), as expected:

```
query UnitTopicActivities {
  unitTopicActivities {
    activity_id
    activity_specific_id
    id
    topic_id
  }
}
```

If I add in the topic (thus a subquery to another table) then it gets about 50% of the stuff in the topic table the first time its queried and then is faster the next time:

```
query UnitTopicActivities {
  unitTopicActivities {
    
    activity_id
    activity_specific_id
    id
    topic_id
    
    topic {
      id
      name
      description
      image
    }
  }
}
```

Finally adding in the activity section produces the same results as originally provided, *activity* is null and it doesnt get through all the data before it times out.

**end edit**

I have tried to look up the issue elsewhere, and note that some people use another tool which stores data to speed up the process, but im not sure this is the solution. I dont think it should be this slow when the SQL command does it in under 0.1 seconds consistently and so expect there are other underlying issues.

Some things im not sure will help but I had been asked for in an unrelated context:

> SHOW CREATE TABLE units_topics;

```
localhost/aM78gzT8nB/       https://remotemysql.com/phpmyadmin/db_sql.php?db=aM78gzT8nB
Your SQL query has been executed successfully.

SHOW CREATE TABLE units_topics

units_topics    CREATE TABLE `units_topics` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `image` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=74 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

> SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "units_topics";

```
localhost/aM78gzT8nB/       https://remotemysql.com/phpmyadmin/db_sql.php?db=aM78gzT8nB
Your SQL query has been executed successfully.

SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "units_topics"

units_topics    MyISAM  10  Dynamic 55  158 8700    281474976710655 2048    0   74  2022-12-01 11:00:21 2022-12-01 11:00:21 
    NULL
    latin1_swedish_ci   
    NULL
```

The code is as follows:

**server.js** (launches an apollo server, this is the node launch file)

```
const apollo = require('@apollo/server');
const apolloStandalone = require('@apollo/server/standalone');
const gqlTools = require('@graphql-tools/merge');
const playGround = require('apollo-server-core');

const schema = [require('./schema/minimumSchema')];

const typeDefs = gqlTools.mergeTypeDefs(...[schema.map((a) => a.typeDefs)]);
const resolvers = gqlTools.mergeResolvers(...[schema.map((a) => a.resolvers)]);

// server function (async bug?)
async function startApolloServer(typeDefs, resolvers) {
  // create an apollo serve rinstance...
  const server = new apollo.ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    plugins: [playGround.ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground()],
  });

  const { url } = await apolloStandalone.startStandaloneServer(server, {
    listen: { port: 4000 },
  });

  console.log(`  Server ready at: ${url}`);
}

startApolloServer(typeDefs, resolvers);
```

**database.js** - this links to the database. Username, password etc left in as itsa  temporary test server.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const graphql = require('graphql/type');

var db = {};

const Date = new graphql.GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'Date',
  description: 'Date custom scalar type',
  serialize(value) {
    return value.getTime(); // Convert outgoing Date to integer for JSON
  },
  parseValue(value) {
    return new Date(value); // Convert incoming integer to Date
  },
  parseLiteral(ast) {
    if (ast.kind === Kind.INT) {
      // Convert hard-coded AST string to integer and then to Date
      return new Date(parseInt(ast.value, 10));
    }
    // Invalid hard-coded value (not an integer)
    return '1';
  },
});

const sequelize = new Sequelize.Sequelize(
  'aM78gzT8nB',
  'aM78gzT8nB',
  'RtPJ3fI68F',
  {
    host: 'remotemysql.com',
    port: '3306',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    dialectModule: require('mysql2'),
    logging: false,
    pool: {
      max: 2,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 30000,
      idle: 20000,
    },
  }
);

let models = [
  require('./models/a_experiment'),
  require('./models/a_flashcards'),
  require('./models/a_phetlabs'),
  require('./models/a_videonotes'),
  require('./models/a_working'),
  require('./models/units_topics'),
  require('./models/units_topics_activities'),
];

models.forEach((model) => {
  const seqModel = model(sequelize, Sequelize.Sequelize);
  db[seqModel.name] = seqModel;
});

Object.keys(db).forEach((key) => {
  if ('associate' in db[key]) {
    db[key].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize.Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
module.exports.Date = Date;
```

**minimumSchema.js** is the file I have defined the types and resolvers in:

```
const db = require('../database');

const typeDefs = `
  type Experiment {
      id: ID!
      points_max: Int
      name: String
      introduction: String
      diagram_link: String
  }
  type Flashcard {
    id: ID!
    topic_id: Int
    side_a: String
    side_b: String
    topic: Topic
  }
  type PhetLab {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    description: String
    embed_code: String
    sim_link: String
    points_max: Int
  }
  type VideoNote {
    id: ID!
    points_max: Int
    name: String
    link: String
    length: Int
  }
  type Working {
    id: ID!
    points_max: Int
    name: String
    description: String
  }
  type Topic {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    description: String
    image: String
  }

  union Activity = Working | Experiment | PhetLab | VideoNote

  type Query {
    unitTopicActivities(query: String): [UnitTopicActivity]
    unitTopicActivity(id: ID!): UnitTopicActivity
  }

  type UnitTopicActivity {
      id: ID!
      topic_id: Int
      activity_id: Int
      activity_specific_id: Int
      topic: Topic
      activity: [Activity]
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    unitTopicActivities: async (obj, args, context, info) =>
      db.units_topics_activities.findAll(),
    unitTopicActivity: async (obj, args, context, info) =>
      db.units_topics_activities.findOne({ where: { id: args.id } }),
  },
  UnitTopicActivity: {
    topic: async (obj, args, context, info) =>
      db.units_topics.findOne({ where: { id: obj.topic_id } }),
    activity: async (obj, args, context, info) => {
      switch (obj.activity_id) {
        case 1:
          db.a_videonotes.findByPk(obj.activity_specific_id);
          break;
        case 2:
          db.a_experiment.findByPk(obj.activity_specific_id);
          break;
        case 3:
          db.a_phetlabs.findByPk(obj.activity_specific_id);
          break;
        case 5:
          db.a_working.findByPk(obj.activity_specific_id);
          break;
      }
    },
  },
  Flashcard: {
    topic: async (obj, args, context, info) =>
      db.units_topics.findOne({ where: { id: obj.topic_id } }),
  },
};

module.exports.resolvers = resolvers;
module.exports.typeDefs = typeDefs;
```

**Then the models** - these are the files sequelize uses so it knows what the database looks like:

The first five, experiment, working, flashcards, phetlabds and videonotes just store the activity names, the descriptions and the points required. Some other basic info and they are all a little different but basically all server the same purpose and arent usually queried on their own.

**a_experiment.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('a_experiment', {
    id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    points_max: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 100
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    introduction: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    diagram_link: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'a_experiment',
    timestamps: false,
    indexes: [
      {
        name: "PRIMARY",
        unique: true,
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "id" },
        ]
      },
    ]
  });
};
```

**a_flashcards.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('a_flashcards', {
    id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    topic_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    side_a: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    side_b: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'a_flashcards',
    timestamps: false,
    indexes: [
      {
        name: "PRIMARY",
        unique: true,
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "id" },
        ]
      },
    ]
  });
};
```

**a_phetlabs.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('a_phetlabs', {
    id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    embed_code: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    sim_link: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    points_max: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'a_phetlabs',
    timestamps: false,
    indexes: [
      {
        name: "PRIMARY",
        unique: true,
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "id" },
        ]
      },
    ]
  });
};
```

**a_videonotes.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('a_videonotes', {
    id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    points_max: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 100
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    link: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    length: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'a_videonotes',
    timestamps: false,
    indexes: [
      {
        name: "PRIMARY",
        unique: true,
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "id" },
        ]
      },
    ]
  });
};
```

**a_working.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('a_working', {
    id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    points_max: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 100
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'a_working',
    timestamps: false,
    indexes: [
      {
        name: "PRIMARY",
        unique: true,
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "id" },
        ]
      },
    ]
  });
};
```

**units_topics.js** - This lists the topics, with their names, descriptions etc. Again this is unlikely the be queries on its own:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('units_topics', {
    id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    image: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'units_topics',
    timestamps: false,
    indexes: [
      {
        name: "PRIMARY",
        unique: true,
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "id" },
        ]
      },
    ]
  });
};
```

**units_topics_activities.js** - This is the table that is likely to be queried, and pulls together the topics and the activities from any of the five different activity databases. Its a link between the topicId and the activityIds.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('units_topics_activities', {
    id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    topic_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    activity_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    activity_specific_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'units_topics_activities',
    timestamps: false,
    indexes: [
      {
        name: "PRIMARY",
        unique: true,
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "id" },
        ]
      },
    ]
  });
};
```

Finally there the **init-models.js** file which simply initialises the database structures in sequelize:

```
var DataTypes = require('sequelize').DataTypes;

var _a_experiment = require('./a_experiment');
var _a_flashcards = require('./a_flashcards');
var _a_phetlabs = require('./a_phetlabs');
var _a_videonotes = require('./a_videonotes');
var _a_working = require('./a_working');
var _units_topics = require('./units_topics');
var _units_topics_activities = require('./units_topics_activities');

function initModels(sequelize) {
  var a_experiment = _a_experiment(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var a_flashcards = _a_flashcards(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var a_phetlabs = _a_phetlabs(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var a_videonotes = _a_videonotes(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var a_working = _a_working(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var units_topics = _units_topics(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var units_topics_activities = _units_topics_activities(sequelize, DataTypes);

  return {
    a_experiment,
    a_flashcards,
    a_phetlabs,
    a_videonotes,
    a_working,
    units_topics,
    units_topics_activities,
  };
}
module.exports = initModels;
module.exports.initModels = initModels;
module.exports.default = initModels;
```

Comment: Please read [mre], specifically the part about **minimal**. If you have no idea whatsoever why something is not working, just dumping your whole project into the question is **not** a solution. You actually have to do some more work and research yourself.

Comment: So I cut out 90pc of the program, put the types all in one file and removed commenting where required. I appreciate its long, but I'm assuming the slowness of the query is because of the complexity in the relationship between the database tables. Sorry it's long, but the simple stuff all works fine. Happy to take suggestions for what to research what might help me.

Comment: My suggestion would be to remove some of the complexity part by part, and measuring performance in each step to narrow down what part is causing it.

Comment: Added some other test queries. Basically when it needs to look at more than one table, thats when its going slow. This doesnt help the problem with not acquiring all the required data from the individual tables.